# how keep the radio button position at selected one when changes from portrait to landscape

Tags: android

how android radio button code but when changes from portait to landscape selected possition appear

Comment: Its a little difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to ask here. Could you clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably because you are creating them again in this state in onCrete.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) carefully. Then maybe try to save the toogle buttons state in shared preferences or in a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

When screen rotates application starts again so 
set it programatically in your code of onstart method like radiobutton.setchecked(true);